# Use ALTER LOGIN to change User's own Password

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that runs the following:

```
'ALTER LOGIN ' + @Login + ' WITH PASSWORD = ''' + @Password + ''''
```

I get the following error message:

Cannot alter the login 'aUser', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

HOWEVER, if I make add the user to the SysAdmin role, then it is successful. If I remove the user from SysAdmin, I get the error message again, so it appears to be user rights.

The problem is, I need users to be able to change their own passwords, and the ALTER LOGIN command does not seem to allow for that, even though [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828.aspx) says:

> A principal can change the password, default language, and default database for its own >login.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I think to perform an ordinary password change for a user, who doesn't have `ALTER ANY LOGIN`, you must supply the `OLD_PASSWORD` parameter also. This would match the example from the older [`sp_password`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174428.aspx) stored procedure:

> The following example shows how to use ALTER LOGIN to change the password for the login Victoria from B3r1000d#2-36 to V1cteAmanti55imE. This is the preferred method. User Victoria can execute this command without additional permissions. Other users require ALTER ANY LOGIN permission:

```
ALTER LOGIN Victoria WITH 
     PASSWORD = 'V1cteAmanti55imE' 
     OLD_PASSWORD = 'B3r1000d#2-36';
GO
```

Comment: sp_password 'old', 'new' appears to not work from within an application, while this does.

Answer (score 2):

You can **have your application run as a user with sufficient rights**. For that, you would create a service account for the application in SQL Server, and then have your application run as that user.

However, it might be better to **create a Users table for your application** and manage this data there, rather than allowing your users direct access to altering logins.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using following script (You can create as proc)

declare @l sysname = suser_sname();
declare @x nvarchar(max) =
'alter login [' + @l  + '] with default_database = Northwind';
exec (@x);

Something similar You can use with other login settings.