# How can a user change their own password for an Azure SQL Server database with SQL Authentication?

Tags: sql-server, azure

After running these commands against an Azure SQL Server (in SSMS or using a command line utility):

```
-- run in the master table to create the login   
    CREATE LOGIN SusanDBA with password= 'U$3r---Pa55W0rd!!'  

-- run against AnotherDB (not the master db)  
    CREATE USER  SusanDBA from LOGIN SusanDBA
```

SusanDBA can login to open a connection to the AnotherDB but cannot execute the Alter Login command to change the password. This reportedly has to be done against the master database. But we don't want the user to connect to the master db for security reasons.

The command

```
 Alter Login SusanDBA  
     with PASSWORD = 'U$3r---Pa55W0rd!!---'  
     OLD_PASSWORD='U$3r---Pa55W0rd!!'
```

Gets the response

> Msg 5001, Level 16, State 3, Line 1   User must be in the master
>   database.

An administrator with appropriate master privileges can change the password but that kind of defeats the purpose: the administrator now knows the user's password.

Constraints:
- We are not in a position to use AD in this case so its SQL Authentication.
- We would like to use a command prompt utility like SQLCMD.

Comment: Can you just drop and recreate the user? Otherwise I would follow the recommendations posted [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-manage-logins/).

Comment: Zane - Thanks for the prompt response. I spent some time with that helpful article already. It does explain how to allow an account with admin rights to change the password (as in the ALTER command in my question) but the non-administrative user cannot make the change by running such a command. We could do it with an app and a service account (perhaps that is what you are suggesting) but this is an educational setting to help people understand databases.

Comment: Notably, this question/answer  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250176/use-alter-login-to-change-users-own-password) is close. But as noted, that syntax does not seem to work in Azure.

Comment: can you try following the tutorials used on this [github by Jess Boreland](https://github.com/grrlgeek/azure-sql-server/blob/master/Azure%20SQL%20DB%20Logins.sql)

Comment: Okay I think I follow now. Your issue has nothing to do with Azure then. The problem you're having is a permissions issue. Can you have link to your [active directory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/) and then have the users manage their item through windows. If you end up giving the users permissions to manage the Master DB you're going to have a bad time.

Comment: Zane thx again - As noted, no AD. I don't have access to the Active Directory for the users. Students are creating their own servers in their own accounts and creating SQL Authentication users.  I THINK this DOES have to do with Azure because it comes down to how databases are differently provisioned. The logins/passwords are in the master table so the ALTER LOGIN command has to be executed there. But we don't want the users to access it. Agreed! Don't give users permissions to manage the master database. And connections in Azure are database specific (no USE DB command allowed).

Comment: After further efforts I see that if I run the CREATE USER command shown above against the master database, the users can change their own passwords and, although they can see the names of all the databases on the server, master database rights are otherwise minimal. Not a solution perhaps, but a work around.

Comment: Microsoft support is suggesting I use Contained Users to avoid adding logins in the master database. I think that solves it!

Answer (score 5):

Correct syntax on March 2021

```sql
ALTER LOGIN [login] WITH PASSWORD='XXX' OLD_PASSWORD='NNN';
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
ALTER USER userName WITH PASSWORD='newPassword' OLD_PASSWORD='oldPassword';
```

also reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: both links are the same

Comment: `WITH PASSWORD` can be used only if the user is a database-authenticated user and not a master-database LOGIN.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new easy option https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage?view=azuresql

> Important
>
> The name of the Server admin account can't be changed after it has
> been created. To reset the password for the server admin, go to the
> Azure portal, click SQL Servers, select the server from the list, and
> then click Reset Password. To reset the password for the SQL Managed
> Instance, go to the Azure portal, click the instance, and click Reset
> password. You can also use PowerShell or the Azure CLI.