# Change password of login in SQL Server without sysadmin permission

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to change a login password if I do not have sysadmin permissions? In that case, what are the commands to do that?

Comment: Technically, you only need `ALTER ANY LOGIN` permission. Practically, that probably still means you need to be a sysadmin. [However, that doesn't apply if you're changing your own password and you still know the current one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6250176/4137916).

Comment: The problem is that I do not have control over the server, would it still be possible to use `ALTER ANY LOGIN`?

Comment: Define what you mean by "control". You can log in to SQL Server, but you are not a sysadmin? You have administrative access to the machine that SQL Server is on, but you can't log in to SQL Server? You're trying to hack a server that you have no business being on at all?

Comment: I can access the server, execute queries, but I cannot set my user as sysadmin.

Comment: Then the only password you can alter is your own, and then only if you know your current password. Otherwise, you need a sysadmin to help you out.

Comment: I've been able to change the password of another login as a public role login thats been granted ALTER ANY LOGIN only (no other permissions granted) without having to provide the old password. (SQL 2012). @jeroen mostert any reasons why?

Comment: @XingzhouLiu: I'm assuming the OP doesn't have `ALTER ANY LOGIN` permission now, so any way you slice it, a sysadmin would have to at least grant *that*. Also, there are few practical scenarios where you want to give someone `ALTER ANY LOGIN` permission, because there's so much you can screw up with that, security-wise, even if you can't make yourself admin. It would make more sense to have an `EXECUTE AS` stored procedure that changes a password/passwords for accounts that need this.

Comment: @JeroenMostert if I know my current password, how could I alter it?

Comment: Tried following the link I provided? It documents exactly that in the answers.

Comment: I tried, but it says that the password is too recent to be changed.

Comment: you need to talk to your dba unless you can wait. you can't change password policies without her/him.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert good point. Didn't fully process the question.